# Trying to ''npm start" my vue.js build, but i get this error: This relative module was not found:

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, vue.js, mamp-pro

I'm trying to use node.js as my server and vue.js as my client side.
I'm building a chat application with both, with integrated stuff like Axios, Express, Sequelize and vuetify.

The project has been silent for a week of 2 due to a few complications.

I tried to start it back up again and i got this error on my server side:

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                          4:25:16 PM

This relative module was not found:

- ./src/main.js in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js

I've tried to change paths, restart servers and recreate files.

I'm quite new to Vue, so i have no clue what to do and i couldn't find an appropriate answer anywhere.

Here is the webpack.base.conf file

````
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const config = require('../config')
const vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

const createLintingRule = () => ({
  test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
  loader: 'eslint-loader',
  enforce: 'pre',
  include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
  options: {
    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter'),
    emitWarning: !config.dev.showEslintErrorsInOverlay
  }
})

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...(config.dev.useEslint ? [createLintingRule()] : []),
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    // prevent webpack from injecting useless setImmediate polyfill because Vue
    // source contains it (although only uses it if it's native).
    setImmediate: false,
    // prevent webpack from injecting mocks to Node native modules
    // that does not make sense for the client
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty'
  }
}```

It should just start the build like a regular app, but sadly.
````